# Difference between Kotlin plugins

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

What are the differences between these three Kotlin plugins and what do they actually do?

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.6.20"
}
```

The third one seems to be the recommended way specially when using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These plugins provide integration with different other Gradle plugins. They both setup compiling Kotlin for the JVM, but aim to interoperate with different other tools.

- **`org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` or `kotlin-android`**

  This plugin offers integration of Kotlin with [the Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/build), which should also be applied to the project. The Kotlin compilations are set up to be included in the builds of Android variants (e.g. `debug`, `release`, `testDebug` etc.)

  The IDs `kotlin-android` and `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` designate the same Gradle plugin. The only difference is that the "full" ID `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` can be used for resolving the plugin from the Gradle Plugin Portal, while the shorter ID `kotlin-android` can only be used for applying the plugin if you already have it on the build classpath (i.e. it's added elsewhere).
- **`org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`** (also has a shorter alias `kotlin`)

  This is the plugin for building Kotlin projects that target JVM without Android support.

  The plugin offers integration with [the Gradle `java` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) (as well as `java-library` or `application`). The project that applies this plugin can also use Java sources. The Kotlin compilations are wired with the `java` plugin's source sets (`main` and `test` by default)

Normally you should only apply one of these plugins, depending on whether you target Android or "standard" JVM. If you need to target both platforms, you should use the Kotlin Multiplatform plugin by ID `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform`, which adds the DSL to setup the targets in the project. Those might include `jvm()` and `android()`, as well as other targets: JS, WASM, Kotlin/Native.

Comment: Planning to migrate this Android project to KMM soon, is `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` the one should I use as I want to omit the classpath? I am trying to use `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` and you are correct as it gives me error upon syncing `The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.`

Comment: While you only have Android, you can use `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android`. Then at some point you will have to migrate to `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform` – either at the point when you add more target platforms or at some time before that. In the latter case, you can setup Kotlin Multiplatform to build just the single Android target for the time being.

Comment: Or it's already okay to use `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was such a great answer!

Comment: Sorry I just want to follow up as I am getting error with kapt after changing to multiplatform. `An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt', version: '1.6.20-M1']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'.
   > Extension with name 'kotlin' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext, base, defaultArtifacts, sourceSets, reporting, java, javaToolchains, buildOutputs, android, androidComponents, play, googleServices, ksp, kapt]`. Using `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version "${kotlin_version}"`

Comment: We can't set `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform` in Android `build.gradle` right?  We can only set it at shared module `build.gradle` after setting up KMM?

Comment: The above issue is due to order of plugins, kotlin android should be placed before kapt and other kotlin related plugins.

Comment: It is possible to use the Multiplatform plugin in an Android application module, but a lot of setup guides recommend having a separate, shared Multiplatform library module just to make the project structure cleaner. So it's up to you. As for the Kapt plugin – yes, you have to apply it after the other Kotlin plugin.